# Configuring Remote Shut Down with UPS

Tags: hyper-v, rdp

A similar question has been asked but there are differences to my situation.
1) A Hyper-V Core machine running three VMs (XPProSP3) (Win2003SP2) it is a system we inherited and migrated from Physical to Virtual.
2) I am trying to prepare a CMD file so that the UPS will allow closing down the three  machines in an orderly fashion and without any operator intervention (I am often travelling) but have run up against the following

(A) I don't know how to get around the Ctrl+Alt+Del requirement - this is the main problem.
(B) On another server not in the same Domain I simply have used (for at least the last 3 years) an RDP session within a CMD file and with a Shutdown command in the Program Tab and that works very well.
(C) If as an alternative I try to issue the command from the machine that controls the UPS - ie shutdown /s /f / t 60 /m \"IP Address" I get Access Denied (5) 
(D) I will be faced with the same problem when I try to close down the Hyper-V server smoothly so I hope my question is timely.

3) As a result of experimenting with RDP however one machine has developed a black screen which I cannot remove.  This is more annoyance factor than anything else but I would prefer my original screen back.  Looking at various comments and solutions that I have tried - none work!

Thanks for any guidance,

Jean

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Hyper-V 2012 gracefully shutdown when UPS battery running out](https://serverfault.com/questions/464278/hyper-v-2012-gracefully-shutdown-when-ups-battery-running-out).  This may have a workable solution.  The hypervisor should be able to notify the clients to shutdown gracefully.

It appears that Windows can detect some UPS models. They show up in the same manner as a battery in a laptop and are managed in the same way.

If all else fails look at the model used by NUT (Network UPS Tool).  One process monitors the UPS and notifies the various clients to shutdown.  There is at least one client for Windows.  There is now a NUT server beta release.

Once the decision to shutdown is made, it is important to finish the shutdown.  Otherwise you can end up with some systems running and other shutdown without a way to automatically restart them.

Comment: Hi Bill - will look and see - we are at present using PowerChute which came with the UPS and it has worked well but I am not sufficiently experienced with powershell and Hyper-V core as yet...

Answer (score 0):

Best way: Get a UPS with a network management card. After you install the agent service in each vm and the host, and you setup them to shutdown when a ups event happen. (like for apc, the agent is called 'apc powerchute network shutdown')

Comment: We are stuck with what we have - a Smart UPS from APC!

Comment: @JeanRouge Good, as check on the back of it, the network adapter usualy slide there. If you can add it you will have a plastic cover with two screw there.

Comment: @JeanRouge to see what model to use; [APC UPS Network Management Card (NMC) Compatibility Chart](http://www.apc.com/site/support/us/en/faq/?page=content&country=ITB&lang=en&locale=en_IN&id=FA237786&redirect=true)

Comment: Hi Guys - I know it has been 2 years since the question was posted but I just wanted to say that I finally worked out a set of scripts that do the job.  They work when I test them but I am not sure they have worked as expected in the one real power-out we had!  Anyway thanks to everyone, I've been distracted with other things going on in my business but I ought to have posted thanks before - sorry! Jean